# derivative vanishes

Tags: derivatives, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

I'm seeing from the Professor's notes that the that the derivative of the Euclidean scalar product squared $||y(x)||^2 = \langle y(x), y(x)\rangle$  simply vanishes. That is $\frac{d}{dx} ||y(x)||^2=0$. I've got no clue why.
Here $y(x)$ is the solution of the DGL $y(x)'=Ay(x)$. $A$ is a $n\times n$-matrix in this case and $y(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Anyone can help me?

Comment: It seems like a condition is missing. Given your conditions, choosing $A=1$ is a counterexample. Then $y=ce^x$, $\|y\|^2=c^2e^{2x}$ and $(\|y\|^2)^\prime\neq0$ for any $x$, let alone all $x$.

Comment: Pardon, A is a $n X n$-matrix in this case and y is a function from $ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Is $A$ skew-symmetric, by chance?

Comment: Our Professor prooves it later in his script. Or has it to be the condition right now?

Comment: If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then the "vanishing derivative condition" holds, while for a general $A$ this is not true. It's therefore important to clarify exactly what was being assumed, and what was being claimed as a conclusion. :)

Comment: ok, I guess then it must be skew-symmetric here. He might have forgotten to mention it. But why then the vanishing derivative condition" holds?

Comment: $\langle y(x), y(x)\rangle$, the scalar product (a form of metric) sends a pair of functions to a function. The question is which one? clearly if $\langle y(x), y(x)\rangle = z(x)$ for some function dependent on x, this could not be the case. In other words, the scalar product (and by extension metrics) map a pair of functions to a constant. It is, crudely speaking, the quadrance/magnitude of the function $y(x)$ you are dealing with here.

Comment: It could be the other way around. The professor assumes that the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}\|y(x)\|^2=0$ and he proves that $A$ is skew symmetric.

Comment: Incidentally, this is a good question in principle, but I haven't yet upvoted because of the ambiguity in the hypotheses on $A$ (without which my answer is something of a wild guess at interpretation). If you can discover exactly what's being assumed about $A$ in your notes, please add it to the question body.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}\newcommand{\Transp}[1]{#1^{\mathsf{T}}}$If $y' = Ay$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \Brak{y(t), y(t)}
  &= \Brak{y'(t), y(t)} + \Brak{y(t), y'(t)} \\
  &= 2\Brak{y(t), y'(t)} \\
  &= 2\Brak{y(t), Ay(t)}
  = 2\Brak{\Transp{A}y(t), y(t)}.
\end{align*}
If $\Transp{A} = -A$, the last expression is equal to $-2\Brak{y(t), Ay(t)}$, implying
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \Brak{y(t), y(t)} = 0.
$$

Conversely, if $y' = Ay$ and
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t = 0} \Brak{y(t), y(t)}
  = 2\Brak{y(0), Ay(0)}
  = 2\Brak{y(0), \Transp{A}y(0)}
$$
for *every* initial condition $y(0) = y_{0}$, then
$$
0 = \Transp{y_{0}}\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(A + \Transp{A})\bigr] y_{0}\quad\text{for every $y_{0}$.}
$$
By the spectral theorem, $\tfrac{1}{2}(A + \Transp{A})$ (the symmetric part of $A$) has real eigenvectors; letting $y_{0}$ run through an eigenbasis shows $\frac{1}{2}(A + \Transp{A}) = 0$, i.e., $A = -\Transp{A}$.